# Windows Installed But No Boot

Tags: windows-10, boot

My PC suddenly stopped booting even though I didn't install or change anything. The error was ending with "D:\windows\system32\logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt". When I turned on the computer, it was just giving the blue screen with "0xc000021a" error code, getting restared and trying to fix it but then the final error: "Automatic Repair Couldn't repair your PC".

I thought that this a good chance to learn how to fix hard errors like these and began to research for the errors. I found [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/dwindowssystem32logfilessrtsrttrailtxt-windows-10/62386946-c48b-4079-915a-f53c6e28ee1a) and tried the commands with the troubleshoot option:

> `bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
>   bootrec.exe /fixmbr
>   bootrec.exe /fixboot`

​

But bootrex.exe /fixboot command gave the error "Access denied" and it didn't work. So I tried [another recommandation](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-fix-issues-your-boot-records) which made things worse. I tried the bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force command. Now, when I turn on the computer, there is the error "No bootable device. Please restart your computer". Now, I have Windows Installation Media USB. I can go to Command Prompt and see that my files is kept in D:\ with all windows folders. However, I have no idea how to make my PC boot.

Now, I can probably just install the Windows without keeping my files although there are important thing that I don't want to lose so I'm trying to execute the Windows somehow and reach my files. Can you help me about that?

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Ugh.  Outdated help. bootrec.exe /fixmbr write to a part of the disk where in ancient times we stored a boot record. These days that is long gone in favour of UEFI.  Messing with that is likely to make things worse.  (Note that I am making assumptions herem namely that a standard win10 install was done in normal EFI mode and that there was no explicit effort to use MBR and BIOS mode, A safe-ish guess but still a guess).

Comment: Remove the hard drive and use a hard drive to usb adapter to connect it to another PC, then use windows explorer to browse the drive if you can, then copy the files you need to another storage device.

Answer (score 1):

You can [reinstall Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026528/windows-reset-or-reinstall-windows-10), trying to *keep* all your files and applications. That said, to be safe, **make a disk image** to another HDD, or large enough USB drive. Since you can't boot your PC, you need rescue media such as a bootable USB flash drive or DVD, made on a another machine.

A third-party imaging tool such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/) can make rescue media using the [WinPE OS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro).

- Boot from the rescue drive or DVD.
- Make a disk image, or at least use the WinPE file explorer to copy data to an external drive.
- Some of these tools can [fix some boot problems](https://kb.macrium.com/KnowledgebaseArticle50168.aspx) *without* reinstalling Windows.
- If boot repair fails, then try reinstalling [Windows 10 downloaded from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10), using the repair option, keeping files.

**N.B.** Since you state, "My PC suddenly stopped booting even though I didn't install or change anything," find the cause of the issue. Is your HDD failing? Did malware cause the issue?

Comment: Thank your for your response! I have achieved to use "bootrec /fixboot" command with some instructions. Now, I am not seeing the No Bootable Device error anymore. But blue screen error is persisting with error code "0xc000021a" and than, there is another blue screen with text: Recovery, Your PC couldn't start properly with error code "0xc0000001". I can't even use Safe Mode! So, what I understand with your writing is there is no way to repair my PC without reinstalling Windows. Is it true? Is there something I can do about that Recovery error or should I stop trying to fix and backup my files?

Comment: First image the disk, or at least back up files.

Comment: This. First check if your backups work and are up to date.  If you have no backups make some. You can do this by booting from a CD or USB pendrive or anything else but the disk with the broken OS on it. Then make backups. then test backups (no backup is good unless tested!). Only then try to fix or reinstall.